# Select biggest values from table

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have problem with preparing query for SQLite database.
I wanna select **city**, **name** and **surname** from **data** table, where num1 is equal or greater than 50% of total nums1 in group. If any of record don't have 50% or more, then two fields num2 are filled with new values and we must select biggest one.

Input:

```
-----------------------------------------------
| city |  name   |  surname |  num1  |  num2  |
-----------------------------------------------
|  LA  | John    | Smith    |  1237  | "none" |
|  LA  | Frank   | Brooks   |  2671  | "none" |
|  LA  | Elliott | Watson   |  649   | "none" |
|  NY  | Ward    | Ward     |  984   | "none" |
|  NY  | Maria   | Anders   |  1861  |  9774  |
|  NY  | Dave    | Kirk     |  1582  |  8885  |
-----------------------------------------------
```

Required output:

```
-----------------------------
| city |  name   |  surname |
-----------------------------
|  LA  | Frank   | Brooks   |  
|  NY  | Maria   | Anders   |
-----------------------------
```

Could someone help me? Thanks.

Comment: Calculate "50% of total nums1 in group" in CTE/subquery and use in outer query.

Comment: *If any of record don't have 50% or more, then two fields num2 are filled with new values and we must select biggest one.* What if num2 has the same value (numeric or "none") for such rows?

Comment: Do you mean 50% of the average per city?

Comment: @Akina When all num2 in one city are "none", then we take biggest num1. When all num2 in city is not "none", then exists two non-equal num2 and we take biggest num2.

Comment: *When all num2 in city is not "none", then exists two non-equal num2* Either it is provided by some constraint (does it exists? show table's DDL) or non-equal values may NOT exist.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query - but note that I don't answer questions with 'wanna' in them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also do:

```
SELECT city, name, surname 
FROM(
  SELECT *, 
    CASE WHEN 0 = MAX(ratio) OVER(PARTITION BY city)
    THEN num2_ =  MAX(num2_) OVER(PARTITION BY city)
    ELSE ratio
    END subset
  FROM(
    SELECT *, 0.5 < (0.0 + num1)/ SUM(num1) OVER(PARTITION BY city) ratio,
      CASE WHEN num2 = 'none' THEN 0 ELSE CAST(num2 AS DECIMAL) END num2_
    FROM source_table))
WHERE subset = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH 
cte1 AS ( SELECT *, 
                 SUM(num1) OVER (PARTITION BY city) total_num1
          FROM source_table ),
cte2 AS ( SELECT *, 
                 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY city 
                                    ORDER BY CASE WHEN num1 > total_num1 / 2 
                                                  THEN 0 
                                                  ELSE 1 END,                                              
                                             CASE WHEN num2 = "none" 
                                                  THEN 0 
                                                  ELSE num2 END DESC, 
                                             num1) rn
          FROM cte1 )
SELECT *
FROM cte2 
WHERE rn = 1
```